# Can't access Ruby server on VM from host machine

Tags: ruby, sinatra, virtual-machine

I have a VM set up running Ubuntu server 14.04. In my VM I have created the following Ruby/Sinatra app:

```
require 'sinatra'

set :environment, :production
set :bind, '0.0.0.0'

get '/' do
  "Hello World!"
end
```

When I execute this using `ruby hello.rb` I get the following output:

```
[2015-03-09 16:58:34] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2015-03-09 16:58:34] INFO  ruby 2.1.5 (2014-11-13) [x86_64-linux]
== Sinatra/1.4.5 has taken the stage on 4567 for production with backup from WEBrick
[2015-03-09 16:58:34] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=2258 port=4567
```

Everything seems to work fine, but when I try to access `localhost:4567` from my host machine (Windows 8.1) I get a `GET http://localhost:4567/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` error (in Chrome).

If I try to access the server from within my VM (ex, by using `wget http://localhost:4567`) it works fine.

I also have Apache2.4 running in my VM, which works fine, but I disabled it when trying to access my Ruby server by running `sudo service apache2 stop`.

What could the problem be? I have no problem running regular Ruby files, and I can access my Ruby/Sinatra app if I use Apache2 with Phusion Passenger. But when  I simply run `ruby hello.rb` I can't access it from my host machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the network adapter for my VM attached to NAT. I was forwarding ports 443, 22 and 80 to my VM, and accessing my server on those ports works fine. Since I was running the Ruby WEBrick server on the default port 4567, I just had to forward port 4567 from my host machine to my VM as well.

After that change, typing `http://localhost:4567` into my web browser served up the content from my Ruby file.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost` refers to your *local host*, which in the case of Windows is not the same as your Ubuntu instance.

You'll need to connect to your Ubuntu instance IP directly, whatever that is. Usually you can find out with `ip addr` or `ifconfig`.

If you need a friendly DNS name you can put in your browser, [xip.io](http://xip.io/) provides one.

If you're using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com/) then you can configure port forwarding so you can still use `localhost` if you want. Without port forwarding you will not be able to connect indirectly.

Comment: I have port forwarding set up for my VM. When I have my Apache server running on my VM (which it is by default), I have no trouble accessing it from my host machine (i.e. typing localhost into my browser would bring up whatever I have at the document root of my server in my VM).

I tried the same thing on my friends MAC (not using a VM) and we came across the same problem. So I think the problem may not be specific to the VM (which is Oracle VM VirtualBox).

`ifconfig` gives me `inet addr:10.0.2.15`, but typing `10.0.2.15` into my browser does nothing.

Comment: You can't connect to port 80, you'd need to visit `http://10.0.2.15:4567/` if that's the port you're using. Don't forget to include the port if you're running on a custom one. Also, it's a "Mac" not a "[MAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address)" which is an entirely different thing.